# Ícones na actionbar não aparecem

Tags: java, android

Tenho um fragment e estou colocando esses dois métodos na classe

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.alerta, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
  }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_new_quote:
            // TODO put your code here to respond to the button tap
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ADD!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

e tenho um arquivo xml que criei na pasta menu

Mas os ícones não querem aparecer na actionbar de jeito nenhum...

Comment: Pode informar o XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolveu o meu problema colocando no onCreate():

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente tirar esse super:

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
```